# High MySQL CPU Usage (300-400%)

Tags: mysql

last days i have problem with my MySQL CPU usage i have average at 300% CPU usage. MySQL Version is 5.7, database have ~150MB Thanks for help at all.

Server specification:

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1225 V2 @ 3.20GHz
16GB DDR3
```

Log from mysqladmin

```
Uptime: 271  Threads: 6  Questions: 202964  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 311  
Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 254  Queries per second avg: 748.944
```

My my.cnf

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

bind-address            = 127.0.0.1

key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
max_connections        = 2000

query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
query_cache_type=ON
query_cache_size=256M

innodb_buffer_pool_size=12G
innodb_log_buffer_size=128M
innodb_write_io_threads = 4
innodb_read_io_threads  = 4
```

mysqltuner log
https://pastebin.com/raw/xv4FPjpe

findfragtables.sql log
https://pastebin.com/raw/TGP5qjtV

ulimit -a
https://pastebin.com/raw/AeYKtqHH

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
https://pastebin.com/raw/bEZG5GEc

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS (30.10.2018 12:28 UTC+2)
https://pastebin.com/raw/1zFsTYNf

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
mysql    15632  277  8.8 16271348 1447256 ?    Sl   13:58 169:28 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: What are the queries being executed? Are there more queries being executed than normal? Your question is very vague about this, we cannot guess why it's suddenly higher based on this information

Comment: Its mostly select queries 80% i quess, i didn't change any of vars, i have always problem with cpu usage like 200-250% but never above 300% maybe there is some vars from cnf can be configurated better

Comment: Try to launch `mysqltuner` and show its output.

Comment: i added mysqltuner log in main thread

Comment: The first obvious thing is that you have allocated 12g to your InnoDB cache.  Yet your db is less than 1g.  You should reduce it immediately to 8gb.  Are all your tables InnoDB or do you have a mix?

Comment: My main database have all tables InnoDB but other databases have MyIsam too. I changed innodb to 8gb

Comment: You should also reduce your innodb_buffer_pool_instances to match that setting with 8gb.  There should be 1gb per buffer pool instance.

Comment: i changed that to 8gb and still memory uses at 6% and cpu at 220%

Comment: Run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and add the output to the question.  So reducing the memory allocation brought the cpu use down to 220% from 300?

Comment: I think yes, added status in first post. Thank generally for your help

Comment: For now there is 160% cpu, its a proper value?

Comment: @Piotr3k1447  The end of your SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS includes 4970813.64 reads/s which should be considered EXTREMELY abnormal.  
Please post text results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  after a WORKING day, SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; and from your OS a report from ulimit -a so we can see your OS limits.  Is your primary data on SSD or rotating disk?

Comment: @WilsonHauck This server running 2-3 online web reservation systems, there is only live connections. I have normal HDD disk. findfragtables log and ulimit log in first post. Thank you for your willingness to help.

Comment: @piotr3k1447  Your results posted to nopaste.xyz can not be accessed by me due to questionable SSL being used.  Please repost results to pastebin.com where the SSL is current.  Guest account at pastebin.com has no fees that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

When your entire dataset fits in the buffer pool, then there's no need to wait for I/O, which is often the bottleneck because it's so much slower than RAM.

So if you run a lot of read-only queries against data that's already in RAM (the buffer pool), then the constraining resource is CPU, as it scans and searches data from RAM. That's why your CPU load seems like it's so high. It's just steadily busy doing work, because it doesn't have to wait for anything else.

Evidence is in the InnoDB status under "BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY":

> Pages read 7814, created 70, written 3805
>   7.32 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 3.55 writes/s
>   Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000

The "created" statistic is the number of pages that had to be loaded into the buffer pool for the first time. It's so low because practically all the pages are already in the buffer pool.

The "hit rate" is the number of times a query requested a page and it was already in the buffer pool, so no need to load it from disk again. This is 1000/1000, indicating that every time a page was requested, it was already loaded. Or at least 99.9% of the time.

After resizing the buffer pool as was suggested, you would probably have restarted your MySQL Server, which would evict the contents of the buffer pool. After restarting, your queries will read pages from disk to restore them to the buffer pool, and therefore they have to wait for I/O. But eventually you'll reach a point where all data is in the buffer pool again, and I predict you'll see the CPU load increase again.

I also notice that in your InnoDB status "ROW OPERATIONS":

> 0.05 inserts/s, 0.50 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 4970813.64 reads/s

Also the rate of queries per second:

> Queries per second avg: 748.944

This means that about 750 queries per second is responsible for nearly 5 million rows read per second. This is over 6,600 rows per query on average. That's

I suspect this is the root cause of your high CPU load. Your queries are scanning a lot of pages on average, even though those pages are in RAM.

That's pretty surprising given that your whole database is only ~150MB.

You should analyze each of your frequently-run queries to figure out if there are some indexes that could help narrow down the searches so you don't have to examine such a high number of rows in each query.

You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or a video of me presenting it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

Answer (score -1):

Try to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_size from:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=12G
```

to be:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
```